# Determine vector equation from parametric equations

Tags: vector, equation

I'm really struggling with a problem at the moment. The problem is to find the equation for the plane that passes through the point (1,1,1) and is parallel to x - 3y - 2z - 4 = 0.

I have determined the direction vector as (1, -3, -2) and then I calculated the parametric equations as these:

```
x(t) = t + 1
y(t) = 1 - 3t
z(t) = 1 - 2t
```

But now I can't figure out how to determine the equation of the plane from those equations. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a math question, not a programming question.  You should ask it on math.stackexchange.com.

But since it's so simple, I'll just tell you how to solve it here.

You started with the plane equation `x - 3y - 2z - 4 = 0`.  Any plane with the equation `x - 3y - 2z + C = 0` (for any real number `C`) is parallel to your original plane.

So if you want the equation of a parallel plane passing through `(1,1,1)`, just plug `(1,1,1)` into to the equation with `C` and then solve for `C`.

```
1 - 3*1 - 2*1 - C = 0
C = 3 + 2 - 1 = 4
```

So the equation of the parallel plane is `x - 3y - 2z + 4 = 0`.

Comment: Thank you! I will make a note to post maths questions in the other forum, thanks for not closing it. Champion.